# Can I shorten or simplify having many constructors in C#?

Tags: c#

I got some advice about constructors but now I have many. Can I simplify these with a function or some other way? Here's my class?

```
public class ContentViewModel
    {
        public ContentViewModel() { }
        public ContentViewModel(Content content)
        {
            this.Content = content;
        }
        public ContentViewModel(string pk)
        {
            this.Content = new Content();
            this.Content.PartitionKey = pk;
            this.Content.Created = DateTime.Now;
        }
        public ContentViewModel(string pk, string rk)
        {
            this.Content = new Content();
            this.Content.PartitionKey = pk;
            this.Content.RowKey = rk;
            this.Content.Created = DateTime.Now;
        }
        public ContentViewModel(string pk, string rk, string user)
        {
            this.Content = new Content();
            this.Content.PartitionKey = pk;
            this.Content.RowKey = rk;
            this.Content.Created = DateTime.Now;
            this.Content.CreatedBy = user;
        }
        public Content Content { get; set; }
        public bool UseRowKey { 
            get {
                return this.Content.PartitionKey.Substring(2, 2) == "05" ||
                       this.Content.PartitionKey.Substring(2, 2) == "06";
            }
        }
        public string TempRowKey { get; set; }

    }
```

I'm using c# 4. Someone said about named and optional arguments. Will that help me?

Comment: If you're working in C# 4.0, you can use [Named and Optional Arguments.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Comment: You could call one constructor from another, passing the default values.

Comment: Yes I am using c#4. I am very interested if I can use the named and optional arguments. Would that make it more clear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
    public ContentViewModel() { }
    public ContentViewModel(Content content)
    {
        this.Content = content;
    }
    public ContentViewModel(string pk): this(new Content)
    {
        this.Content.PartitionKey = pk;
        this.Content.Created = DateTime.Now;
    }
    public ContentViewModel(string pk, string rk): this(pk)
    {
        this.Content.RowKey = rk;
    }
    public ContentViewModel(string pk, string rk, string user): this(pk, rk)
    {
        this.Content.CreatedBy = user;
    }
```

or you could try:

```
    public ContentViewModel(Content content = null, string pk = null, 
                            string rk = null, string user = null)
    {
        this.Content = content ?? new Content();
        if (pk != null) this.Content.PartitionKey = pk;
        if (rk != null) this.Content.RowKey = pk;
        if (user != null) this.Content.CreatedBy = user;
        this.Content.Created = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

With this you can call your constructor setting or missing any of your params, providing them from left to right or using named params as suggested by @Robert Harvey.
Examples:

```
var c = new ContentViewModel();
var c = new ContentViewModel(pk: 'ppp', user: 'marco');
var c = new ContentViewModel(null, 'pk', null, 'marco');
```

Comment: One of the people here said about using named and optional arguements. Would that help me. I am using C# 4.

Comment: As for the second option: The OP does not actually have a constructor that takes `Content` and other values - which makes perfect sense - either you create `content` and assign its values, or you get a ready `content` with values, but not both (note you always set `Content.Created`, but the OP doesn't). Also, the `null` checks assume null is an invalid value - we don't know that, and don't know the default values are not null.

Comment: @Kobi: it's just an example... with the elements we have it's difficult to give more precide info...

Answer (score 2):

Write a single constructor with all arguments:

```
    public ContentViewModel(string pk, string rk, string user)
    {
        this.Content = new Content();
        this.Content.PartitionKey = pk;
        this.Content.RowKey = rk;
        this.Content.Created = DateTime.Now;
        this.Content.CreatedBy = user;
    }
```

Then call that constructor from the other constructors, passing default values for the missing arguments:

```
    public ContentViewModel(string pk) : this(pk, "","") { }
```

Alternatively, you can use [Optional Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) in C# 4.0.

Comment: This is the normal way - a more general constructor calls a more specific constructor passing defaults. This makes it more straightforward to then call the base constructor on the most specific one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for example your constructor

```
public ContentViewModel(string pk)
{
 this.Content = new Content();
 this.Content.PartitionKey = pk;
 this.Content.Created = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Could call

```
public ContentViewModel(string pk, string rk)
```

With a default value for rk using the following syntax:

```
public ContentViewModel(string pk) : this(pk, "defaultRkValue"){}
```

You would substitute some meaningful data for "defaultRkValue"

If you wanted to go really crazy, then your two argument constructor could call your three argument constructor and so on and so forth

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can have just once constructor:

```
public ContentViewModel(string pk, string rk = null, string user = null)
{
    this.Content = new Content();
    this.Content.PartitionKey = pk;
    this.Content.RowKey = rk;
    this.Content.Created = DateTime.Now;
    this.Content.CreatedBy = user;
}
```

You can even call it like:

```
var content = new ContentViewModel("pk");
```

or

```
var content = new ContentViewModel("pk", "rk");
```

or

```
var content = new ContentViewModel("pk", "rk", "user");
```

or even

```
var content = new ContentViewModel("pk", user: "user"); //without rk field
```

Comment: This example uses "Optional and Named Arguments" from C# 4.0.